# Funcionamento do método "Contains()"

Tags: c#, array, .net, contains

Tenho um *array* de `strings`:

```
string[] warnings =
{
"INQUIRY REQUEST",
"ITEM ALREADY EXISTS",
"ITEM NOT FOUND",
"END OF FILE",
};
```

e tenho uma variável com o seguinte valor:

```
status = " 18:46:24:97    INQUIRY REQUEST                                                 ";
```

Ela chega com espaços em branco e com o horário no começo. Eu confiro se o valor atribuído a esta variável esta contido dentro do *array* desta maneira:

```
if (warnings.Any(warning => warning.Contains(status.Trim())))))
{
    // Code here
}
else
{
    // Code here
}
```

Porém a condição cai no `else` mesmo que contenha "INQUIRY REQUEST" dentro da variável `status`. Como posso corrigir ou melhorar essa condição do `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está mandando procurar um palheiro em uma agulha, e obviamente não tem um palheiro inteiro em uma agulha. Em outras palavras está mandando procurar se o texto `sitio do pica pau amarelo` está dentro de um texto `sitio`, e claramente ele não está. O oposto, `sitio` estaria em `sitio do pica pau amarelo`. Então o resultado está correto.

Se fizer o contrário deve resolver seu problema, só não garanto se é o que deseja. Algo assim:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string[] warnings = {
            "INQUIRY REQUEST",
            "ITEM ALREADY EXISTS",
            "ITEM NOT FOUND",
            "END OF FILE",
            };
        var status = " 18:46:24:97    INQUIRY REQUEST                                                 ";
        if (warnings.Any(warning => status.Contains(warning))) WriteLine("achou");
        else WriteLine("não achou");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3dnnAl). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/isX3ll). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/NeedleInHaystack.cs).